# Showing dialog in non-main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, modal-dialog

I have a non-GUI program that sometimes needs to display a dialog to user.
The problem is that my program runs in an infinite loop and when I show a dialog in this loop the execution of program halts until the dialog is dismissed and this is not wanted because my program loop is a background service that must be responsive all time. So I tried running the dialog showing code in another thread but it doesn't work properly: The dialog is shown only one time/the first time and subsequent calls show nothing.

How can I solve this problem?

This is a sample code for you to test the situation:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import threading
import time

def messageBox():
    root=tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('dialog', 'test')
    root.destroy()

while True:
    threading.Thread(target=messageBox).start()
    time.sleep(3)
```

I use Python 3.3.4 on Windows XP

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to make your dialog a separate script, and use the subprocess module to display the dialog in a separate process.